# Cannot set WordWrap option on TextBox inside TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a TextBox that is added to each new tab control tab page that gets created at runtime. All properties are set properly (e.g. Multiline, etc), but when i try to access the textbox from coedbehind there is no option for it. How do I set wordwrap on or off when it's inside a tabcontol's tabpage?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Controls` collection is typed as a collection of `Control` objects. You will need to cast the returned control to `TextBox` first:

```
TextBox textBox = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as TextBox;
if (textBox != null)
{
    textBox.WordWrap = true;
}
```

Comment: I originally tried `(TextBox)tabControl1.Selectedtab.Controls[0].WordWrap = true;` but that didn't work either. I thought that was casting (aswell)?

Comment: @Joey: You lack one pair of paranthesis for that to work: `((TextBox)tabControl1.Selectedtab.Controls[0]).WordWrap`. Your code tries to cast the tab control itself to `TextBox`. The difference between this approach and my code sample is that my code sample will not throw an exception if the returned control turns out not to be a `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
var txtBox= tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
if(txtBox != null)
{
   // do something like txtBox.WordWrap = true;
}
```